# How do you break a nested method calling in different objects?

Tags: java

The situation is as follwing

```
student.studentsPhone.studentsAccount.topUp(xxx)
```

student is an object that has the method studentsPhone which returns the a variable of type Phone and the phone object has a method studentsAccount which returns the a variable of type Account that finally has the required method.

So my question is if I have a student object and no phone, I will get a null pointer exception. Is there a way to cut the line where we wanted? 
bare in mind that I don't want to instantiate everything in the main class. I will just instantiate the Student class.

I though of several approaches

1. Move the method up the heirarchy, but the other objects won't be of any use really
2. in the studentsPhone method I say if `(Phone == null) return;` but its not void and there are other methods after studentPhone

Comment: Another way to solve this problem is by using a 'null-instance'. The instance should be returned once a value is considered `null`, meaning further operations/methods still can be called without a nullpointer exception.

Comment: Please realise that this kind of chaining is considered a [code smell](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/smells/message-chains), because your client code now depends on the exact class structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator for this, something like:

```
String result =  student != null ? (student.studentPhone != null ? (student.studentPhone.studentsAccount != null ? student.studentPhone.studentsAccount.topUp(xxx) :"return"): "return") : "return"
```

or like:

```
boolean isNotNull = student != null ? (student.studentPhone != null ? (student.studentPhone.studentsAccount != null ? true : false): false) : false;

if(isNotNull){
    student.studentPhone.studentsAccount.topUp(xxx);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could throw your own type of runtime exception if there is no phone. Wrap your code in a try/catch block, catching your own exception and then carry on with the rest of your function

```
void doSomeThing() {
    Phone getStudentPhone() {
        if(phone == null) {
            throw new noPhoneException();
        }
        return phone;
    }
}

try {
    student.getStudentPhone().studentsAccount.topUp(xxx);
} catch(noPhoneException e) {
    // say something about no phone existing
}
```